# Document_open macro in Word isn't triggered until VBA-code is changed (insignificantly)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a .docm file with a Document_Open-sub, which calls another sub to open a small userform - or it's supposed to trigger and open - but it doesn't...

If I make changes to the document and save it - it still doesn't work.

If I make **in**significant changes to the VBA-code in the same document (like adding a space character outside a sub) and save it - it suddenly works.

Why does it not work all the time? - and what can I change to make it work?

Additional info (I have no idea if some of it might be relevant)

- In most cases the document is downloaded from an internal website and saved locally.
- The document we've tested with is saved locally in a location which is trusted in Word.
- In cases - where the sub isn't triggered automatically - the sub can be run with ALT+F8 (but that's not what I want).
- The functionality works for some user - and not for others.
- The functionality in the Document_Open-sub depends on a value read in CustomDocumentProperties.

System: Win10 - Word MSO365 build 2110

Edit - code added:

```
Public Sub Subrutine1()
    ThisDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("prop1").Value = " "      'resetting prop1
    UserForm1.Show  'prop1 is set from the userform
End Sub


Private Sub Document_Open()
    
    If ThisDocument.CustomDocumentProperties("prop1").Value = " " Then
        Call Subrutine1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If the file from the internet has code in it (sounds like it does) then you may need to go to the file properties and "unblock" it first for the macros to work. https://thirtysix.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202921675-How-to-Unblock-a-File-Downloaded-from-an-Email-or-the-Internet

Comment: Thank you for your advise, braX - unfortunately it doesn't have any influence.

Comment: You need to post the relevant code and the expected values of the document property field otherwise your question is not relevant to this forum.

Answer (score 0):

### You could rename your Sub "Subrutine1" to "AutoOpen."

I would recommend the following code.

```
Private Sub AutoOpen()
    Dim myForm As UserForm1
    Set myForm = New UserForm1
    myForm.Show
    Unload myForm
    Set myForm = Nothing
End Sub
```

- I would suggest resetting the document property as part of your userform initialization unless you sometimes use it without resetting that.
- I would suggest using a document variable rather than a document property.
- I suspect you would be better served with a document *template* rather than a document. In that case, the macro would be named "AutoNew."